# i am having a problem while calling the value of a key with tkinter .get() function

Tags: tkinter

> Exception in Tkinter callback 100 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\anaconda\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1702, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProject/Financial Project/JournalEntries.py", line
>   29, in Journal
>       self.AccountCode = AccCode[Account_Title.get()] KeyError: '100'

this is my dictionary:

```
 AccCode = {100 : 'Cash',101 : 'Equipments', 102 : 'Supplies' , 103 : 'AccRec' , 104 : 'PreInsurance',
                   200 : 'AccPayable', 201 : 'NotesPay', 202 : 'InterestPayable', 203 : 'AccDepreciation' , 204 : 'Salaries and wages payable',
                   300 : 'Owner Capital', 301 : 'Owner Drawing',
                   400 : 'Service Revenue' , 401 : 'Rent Revenue',
                   500 : 'Salaries and wages Expense' , 501 : 'Utilities Expense' , 502 : 'Rent Expense' , 503 : "Insurance Expense" , 504 : 'Depreciation Expense' , 505 : 'Supplies expense' , 506 : ' Interest Expense' }
```

Although, when I am calling just `print(Account_Title.get())` it is giving me 100 as I am inputting 100 in tkinter entry.
But when `self.AccountCode = AccCode[Account_Title.get()]`
it gives key error.

Comment: Maybe you should try to debug the program. Be aware that 100 <> '100'.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the `key` for ex. `100`, you expect to see the `value` Cash, in the tkinter window.

Using the `textvariable` option in the `Entry` widget, you can call the `get()` on the `textvariable` to get the `key` that you entered in the entry field.

Since all the keys in your dictionary are whole numbers, I have therefore used `IntVar()` to accept only integer values from the `Entry`. To accept a string value from the entry widget, you can use `StringVar()`.

Using `sqlite3`, if the `key` exists in the dictionary, it inserts both the `acc_code` and `acc_value` into the `acc_info` db.

**Code:**

```py
AccCode = {100 : 'Cash',101 : 'Equipments', 102 : 'Supplies' , 103 : 'AccRec' , 104 : 'PreInsurance', 200 : 'AccPayable', 201 : 'NotesPay', 202 : 'InterestPayable', 203 : 'AccDepreciation' , 204 : 'Salaries and wages payable', 300 : 'Owner Capital', 301 : 'Owner Drawing', 400 : 'Service Revenue' , 401 : 'Rent Revenue', 500 : 'Salaries and wages Expense' , 501 : 'Utilities Expense' , 502 : 'Rent Expense' , 503 : "Insurance Expense" , 504 : 'Depreciation Expense' , 505 : 'Supplies expense' , 506 : ' Interest Expense' }

window = tk.Tk()

key = tk.IntVar()
key_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=key)
key_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=4)

value_label = tk.Label(window, width=20)
value_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=4)

# create the database and table
con = sqlite3.connect('acc_info.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acc_table(acc_code NUMERIC, acc_value TEXT)"
cursor.execute(create_table_query)
con.commit()
con.close()

def get_value():
    # get the value entered in the entry field
    entered_key = key.get()

    # if entered key exists in the dictionary
    if entered_key in AccCode.keys():
        con = sqlite3.connect('acc_info.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()
        insert_query = "INSERT INTO acc_table(acc_code, acc_value) VALUES(?,?)"
        entered_data = (AccCode[entered_key], entered_key)
        cursor.execute(insert_query, entered_data)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        value_label.config(text=AccCode[entered_key]+' - Value Inserted')
    else:
        # if key not exists, then print message
        value_label.config(text="Key doesn't exist")

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Insert value to db', command=get_value)
btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=4)

window.mainloop()
```

**The GUI:**

> Enter `key` and press `Insert value to db`

[image: gui window]

> Validation message if an non-existent `key` is entered

[image: GUI with key and value]

Comment: thank you so much but I was inserting the values of key in my sqlite3 table

Comment: like I am just pressing insert button and all of my data will be inserted to the table 
I wanted the user to input the key I.e account code and in the backend the value of the acc code will be inserted to the table column account title

Comment: Hey, I edited the code that now supports insertion to db and also validation messages.